# Strange behaviour upon unchecking 'Show skipped reviews' when at last page of review history

Tags: bug, feature-request, review-history

To reproduce this behaviour, visit the a review queue's history tab. I'll take [First Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/history?skipped=true) as an example. Because of the amount of skipped reviews, checking the option to "Show skipped reviews" increases the number of posts, and consequently the number of pagination links at the bottom of the page also increases. Next, I navigate to the last page of my reviews. Now that I am at this last page of reviews that includes skipped reviews, unchecking the "Show skipped reviews" produces this result:

[image: Screenshot of 'no reviews']

As you can see, I **have** reviewed first questions, but not at the given page number. The url shows `page=21`, leading to the output of no available reviews.

I'm wondering if we should get redirected to the last (closest) page number to that of the one which is not available, when we uncheck the skipped reviews. This could prevent the misleading message of no reviews at all, when the real issue is that there are no available reviews for the given query.

Comment: @CodyGray, Sure, I'd already looked at one of those and now have seen the others. My reasoning was that this is specifically about the review history, and that the other posts don't even have satisfactory answers. Do you mind expounding on your reasoning a bit?

Comment: It's exactly the same situation. The pagination logic is shared by all pages, so it's the same bug, brought about in exactly the same way. Lots of bug reports here don't have satisfactory answers, unfortunately.